# Unrecognized selector sent to instance while adding annotation in MKMapview

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

This is the error I am getting while adding annotations to `MKMapView`.

I have also created a custom class that conforms to the `MKAnnotation` protocol with three `@property`: `coordinate`, `title` and `subtitle`.

[image]

Comment: Please post code of `viewForAnnotation:` method..

Comment: you try my answer ?? try and let me know...

Comment: Post the AnnClass.h and AnnClass.m (something may be wrong with the `coordinate` property getter).  According to the picture, it seems you've named the coordinate property `coord` instead of the required `coordinate`.

Answer (score 0):

here in `viewForAnnotation:` method first check that annotation is which kind of class .. check that its `YourCustomAnnotationClass` then go inside and then check that it is not nil if `nil` then assign `MKAnnotationView` and `alloc` it and then write your code...

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
     static NSString *identifier = @"Current";
     if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[YourCustomAnnotationClass class]]) { /// check here that is your class annotation or not here..

           MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

           if (annotationView == nil) // also check here that it is not nil if nil then alloc it
           {
               annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
           }
           /// write your code here
     }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hii guys I have found what silly mistake i have made, I have named my @property for CLLocationcoordinate2D as Coordinate in my custom annotation class which should not be renamed  because it conforms to KVO complaint so we should use as it is as

@property (nonatomic,assign)CLLocationcoordinate2D coordinate;

by renaming it solved my issue.